# How to setup Key and indexs for SQLite database storing stock price data

Tags: database, sqlite, stock, price

I have a SQLite database that stores company details and share price histories using two tables. The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE details (
epic     CHAR (4),
name     VARCHAR (30),
exchange CHAR (6),
sector   VARCHAR (20),
CONSTRAINT PK_details PRIMARY KEY (
    epic ASC
)
ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK
);

CREATE TABLE data (
epic   CHAR (4),
date   DATE (10),
open   DECIMAL (6, 2),
high   DECIMAL (6, 2),
low    DECIMAL (6, 2),
close  DECIMAL (6, 2),
volume INTEGER (10),
CONSTRAINT PK_data PRIMARY KEY (
    epic ASC,
    date ASC
)
ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK
);
```

When I delete a company from the details table I would like if possible for the deletion process to cascade and delete all the corresponding entries in the data table.

Also, as the data table could be very large - 500 companies, with two years of data for each company, an index needs to be created and I am not sure how to set that up.

Any help or comments on how to improve the above schema would be greatly appreciated.

I have done a bit more reading and added a foreign key to the data table.

```
ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK,
CONSTRAINT epic_FK FOREIGN KEY (
    epic
)
REFERENCES details (epic) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

That seems to work and when a company in the details table is deleted, all corresponding entries in the data table are now deleted.

Also, I have added a unique index to the epic column in the data table with sorting set to ASC and another unique index to both the epic and names columns of the details table, again with sorting set to ASC.

Not sure if the above changes are the best solution though.

Comment: It's all on the [sqlite page](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) including examples for `CREATE INDEX` (index chapter) and cascade `ON DELETE` (in the foreign key chapter).

Comment: I'd read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and stick with using the normal sqlite types for your columns. At the very least make sure you understand how the ones you're using now are treated.

Comment: With the primary key on epic + date on the data table you have a combined index on those two columns already. As epic is the first column in this index it should be sufficient to retrieve data records in a join with the details table.

Your solution should work. The number of records (500 companies x 360 days x 2 years) is just a few hundred thousand records. SQLite should handle that amount pretty easily.

Comment: @Oliver Jakoubek Are the additional unique sorted indexes on epic and epic + names now redundant?

Comment: @w2kpro Those additional indexes should make no difference - for the performance. You might have unique constraints on some columns just for the sake of ensuring unique values. Like I said, performance shouldnt be an issue with those few records.